# C code to generate variable with the combination of a-z and max of 4 char

Tags: c, concatenation

I am trying to write a code that generate variable using a-z only and maximum of 4 char , that means a total of 26*26*26*26 combinations.So here is what i am doing

```
#include<stdio.h>
static char vcd_xyz[4];
static char     vcd_xyz1[2];
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<26;i++)
  {
    vcd_xyz[1] = 'a'+i;
    printf("%d generated variable is   initial is  = %c \n",i,vcd_xyz[1]);

    for(j=0;j<26;j++)
    {
      vcd_xyz[2] = 'a'+j;
      printf("%d generated variable is  = %c \n",j,vcd_xyz[2]);
      //strcat(vcd_xyz[1],vcd_xyz[2]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So it is generating me something like this

```
0 generated variable is   initial is  = a 
0 generated variable is  = a 
1 generated variable is  = b 
2 generated variable is  = c 
3 generated variable is  = d 
4 generated variable is  = e 
5 generated variable is  = f 
6 generated variable is  = g 
7 generated variable is  = h 
8 generated variable is  = i 
9 generated variable is  = j 
10 generated variable is  = k 
11 generated variable is  = l 
12 generated variable is  = m 
13 generated variable is  = n 
14 generated variable is  = o
```

now what i am trying to do is to concatenate these two characters so that i can get a combination like this, aa, ab, ac, ad......ba, bb, bc,bc....ca,cb......and so on, but when i am using

```
strcat(vcd_xyz[1],vcd_xyz[2]);
```

its producing a segmentation fault.I understand that i may be do it in wrong way. can any body tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: indentation is a courtesy to the reader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments of `strcat` are supposed to be *strings* and not *characters*. Just place the characters next to each other like you do now ant it should work. But start with index `0` (as all C arrays start their indexes on zero).

Also, if you later want to print the array as a string, you need a *fifth* character in the array, and that is the string terminator character `'\0'`, and that terminator character needs to be placed after the last character in the array.

Comment: why does he need a fifth character? he barely uses 2

Comment: @NoIdeaForName The OP states that a combination of four is wanted, so a string of four characters needs an array of size five to contain the terminator.

Comment: Well that's work for me..i was having a doubt earlier regarding strcat  "The arguments of strcat are supposed to be strings and not characters".

Answer (score 1):

i followed Joachim Pileborg words and got you this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static char vcd_xyz[5];
static char     vcd_xyz1[2];

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    vcd_xyz[2] = '\0';

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        vcd_xyz[0] = 'a'+i;
        printf("%d generated variable is   initial is  = %c \n",i,vcd_xyz[0]);

        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
           vcd_xyz[1] = 'a'+j;
           printf("%d generated variable is  = %c \n",j,vcd_xyz[1]);
           puts(vcd_xyz);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```