# Unable to pass the generated values from a for loop to a structure

Tags: c, structure, concatenation

As per my [earlier asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089395/c-code-to-generate-variable-with-the-combination-of-a-z-and-max-of-4-char) , i am trying to pass values generated from the code i.e. hashname(variables which are generated in the forth loop, combination of a-z, a four character string) to a structure member, using this code.

```
vcd_xyz[4]='\0';
count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        vcd_xyz[0] = 'a'+i;
       // printf("%d generated variable is   initial is  = %c \n",i,vcd_xyz[0]);

        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
           vcd_xyz[1] = 'a'+j;
          // printf("%d generated variable is  = %c \n",j,vcd_xyz[1]);
         //  puts(vcd_xyz);
          for(int k = 0;k<26;k++)
          {
             vcd_xyz[2] = 'a' + k;
            // puts(vcd_xyz);
             for(int l=0;l<26;l++)
             {
               vcd_xyz[3] = 'a' +l;
               count++;
             sss->Variables[0].hashname = (char*)calloc(strlen((char*)vcd_xyz)+1,sizeof(char));
             strcpy(sss->Variables[0].hashname,(char*)vcd_xyz);
             if(count>(sss->NumVariables))
             {
                break;
             }

              }
          }
        }
    }
```

But as per its output, only last value produced by the for loop is being copied in the structure.I am unable to understand why this is happening.Although vcd_xyz when printed print all the values generated by for loop.

`Variables` is a pointer pointing to a structure `Variable` and `Name`,`NumVariables` and `hashname` are its members.
Structure Variable is a member of structure `sss`
i had declared vcd_xyz as a global variable.

Comment: why are you using this: `sss->Variables[0]`. shouldn't it be equal to number of times the loop are running

Comment: well lets say that `NumVariables` hold the number  value for number of time the values generated by the for loop will be passed to the structure, how will be do that?Means i am getting no clue...

Answer (score 1):

So many problems:

1. <s>You never increase `count`.</s> *Okay, you fixed that.*
2. Maybe you meant `sss->Variables[count]` instead of `sss->Variables[0]`
3. And your condition should be `if(count >= sss->NumVariables)`.
4. You only `break` out of the most inner-most `for`-loop.
5. You don't check if your `calloc` fails.

Comment: #5 must not be used as hashname can be maximum of 4 chars and one variable is being printed,but anyways, i will use that..#4 inner most loop is the one which is producing all the hashname required by me..