# Getting Segmentation fault while assigning memory to Struct variable using calloc

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to allocate memory to a struct variable using calloc but getting segmentation fault.When i tried to debug using ddd, got that error is orignating while assigning first hashname to the member of struct variable.here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static char vcd_xyz[5];
static char     vcd_xyz1[2];
char  getvariablename();
void printmyvalue(char a[]);
void passhashnamevalue(char a[]);
typedef struct Variable_struct
{
char *name;
char *hashname;
}Variable;

typedef struct Newstruct
{
Variable *Variables;
}sss;


int main()
{

 getvariablename();


}

char getvariablename()
{   
    int i,j;
    vcd_xyz[4] = '\0';
   int  count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        vcd_xyz[0] = 'a'+i;
       // printf("%d generated variable is   initial is  = %c \n",i,vcd_xyz[0]);

        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
           vcd_xyz[1] = 'a'+j;
          // printf("%d generated variable is  = %c \n",j,vcd_xyz[1]);
         //  puts(vcd_xyz);
          for(int k = 0;k<26;k++)
          {
             vcd_xyz[2] = 'a' + k;
            // puts(vcd_xyz);
             for(int l=0;l<26;l++)
             {
               vcd_xyz[3] = 'a' +l;
                 count ++;
passhashnamevalue(vcd_xyz);
        //printmyvalue(vcd_xyz);
              // printf("%s\n",vcd_xyz);
              }
          }
        }
    }

    return vcd_xyz[4];
}

void printmyvalue(char a[])
{
printf("%s \n",a);
}

void passhashnamevalue(char a[])
{ sss *SSS;   
SSS->Variables = (Variable *) calloc(15,sizeof(Variable));
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    SSS->Variables[i].hashname = (char*)calloc(strlen((char*)a)+1,sizeof(char));
strcpy(SSS->Variables[i].hashname,(char*)a);
printf("%s",SSS->Variables[i].hashname);
}

}
```

I unable to figure out where i am doing mistake.This code might look like a bit messed up, but its in continuation to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109569/unable-to-pass-the-generated-values-from-a-for-loop-to-a-structure)

Comment: Im not one to nitpick, but "passhashnamevalue" would look a lot nicer as "PassHashNameValue"

Answer (score 4):

```
sss *SSS;   
SSS->Variables = (Variable *) calloc(15,sizeof(Variable));
```

`SSS` is an uninitialised pointer.  You need to allocate memory for it before allocating `SSS->Variables`.

You can either place `SSS` on the stack

```
sss SSS;   
SSS.Variables = calloc(15,sizeof(Variable));
```

or allocate it dynamically on the heap

```
sss *SSS = malloc(sizeof(*SSS));
SSS->Variables = calloc(15,sizeof(Variable));
```

In either case, you need to free any dynamically allocated memory later in your program.  Each call to `malloc` (or `calloc`/`realloc`) must have a later matching call to `free`.

Comment: this worked out for me, a silly mistake from a new programmer indeed.Well all i was trying with this code was to store different `hashname` in the struct, but all this code was doing was printing each hashame 10 times, so i removed the for loop and put Variables[0] and then put a for loop like this `}
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
printf("%s\n",SSS->Variables[i].hashname);
}` but it only printed the first value and then again comes the seg fault..

Comment: If you only set a string for `Variables[0]` then `Variables[1]` will be `NULL`, causing a segfault since `SSS->Variables[1].hashname` will dereference `NULL`.  You can only print values from strings you have set content into.

Comment: That's what i was doing when i was keeping `Variables[j]` in loop instead of `Variables[0]`.means genearting say "n" structure and passing the value of hashname to their member hashname

Comment: when i am assigning structure member hasname, a name generated from for loop, last name generated from for loop is being assigned.What should i do to assign everyname that is being generated.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you're asking.  Its hard to provide enough detail in a comment; could you post a new question for this instead?

Comment: here is my new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112864/unable-to-assign-from-the-initial-hasname-produced-by-a-for-loop-to-a

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the memory to sss *SSS; or you can do one thing.

sss SSS; This will be a instance to it. Now access it via . operator.
SSS.Variables.

In case, it is pointer; then you need to malloc or calloc the SSS memory. Then you can use the -> operator to access the Variable.

Remember, the fundamental -> You need to create the memory first, to access it. When you say sss SSS; This declares and defines the variable SSS.

In the program you have done, you need to allocate the memory first using calloc or malloc.
Then your program will not crash. To catch your errors, you can run valgrind on to the program. This way, you can debug the issue easily. Also, remember to always compile with -g option to generate the elf with debug symbols. You can use gdb also to debug such issues. before launching the application do ulimit -c unlimited. This will generate the core file. You can debug this corefile with gdb. Just do gdb