# How to generate a set of unique hash strings in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random, generator

This code produce 26*26*26*26 hasname (using combinations of a-z)or you can say random names which i want to assign to a structure member.Now when i am assigning that by first allocating that structure member sufficient memory and then using strcpy, only last hashname generated by this code is being passed to the structure i.e zzzz(it is the last hashname).What can i do so that hashname is assigned from the starting.

```
vcd_xyz[4] = '\0';
int  count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    vcd_xyz[0] = 'a'+i;
    for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
    {
        vcd_xyz[1] = 'a'+j;
        for(int k = 0;k<26;k++)
        {
            vcd_xyz[2] = 'a' + k;
            for(int l=0;l<26;l++)
            {
                vcd_xyz[3] = 'a' +l;
                count ++;
                printf("%s\n",vcd_xyz);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i am using

```
sss->Variables[0].hashname = (char*)calloc(strlen((char*)vcd_xyz)+1,sizeof(char));
strcpy(sss->Variables[0].hashname,(char*)vcd_xyz);
```

to copy the hasname produced but it is copying the last hashname produced, so where ever i am using `tr0->Variables[0].hashname = (char*)calloc(strlen((char*)vcd_xyz)+1,sizeof(char));
strcpy(tr0->Variables[0].hashname,(char*)vcd_xyz);` only zzzz get printed.what i am doing wrong or what should i do so that hashname are assigned in a sequential manner.

Comment: Please write whether you want C or C++ solution, remove one of these tags accordingly and write what compiler you are using.

Comment: @LihO: either will work..as i am compiling  in g++

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to realize that `char vcd_xyz[4]` is an array of 4 characters, meaning that you can put there 3 characters + terminating character `'\0'`. If you treat this array as it is null-terminated when it is not, it results in ***undefined behavior***.

What your code actually does is that it iterates through all possible combinations of 4 letters long strings, from `"aaaa"` to `"zzzz"`, leaving the `vcd_xyz` array filled with the last combination (i.e. `"zzzz"`).

---

If you want to generate random 4-letters long string, here's the C-style function you might use:

```
int irand(int min, int max) {
    return ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

it generates random number from `<min;max>` interval and it can be used like this:

```
std::string generateHashTag() {
    char str[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        str[i] = irand('a', 'z');
    str[4] = '\0';
    return std::string(str);
}
```

But in case you want to generate a ***set of unique 4-letters long hash tags***, you will need more complex solution. In C++ you might easily generate these strings in a loop that will put them into an `std::set` container till you have enough of them or you might generate more unique combinations of this string, put all of these into an `std::vector`, shuffle it and pick first `N`, e.g.:

```
const size_t N = 5;
std::set<std::string> myHashTags;

srand(time(0));
while (myHashTags.size() < N)
    myHashTags.insert(generateHashTag());

for (std::set<std::string>::iterator i = myHashTags.begin();
     i != myHashTags.end(); ++i)
     std::cout << *i << ' ';
```

outputs `kemy snwv vnmi wfmm wqeg`. Full example [here](http://ideone.com/Rs0wff).

Comment: I had already done random character variable, but i am unable to pass them in from the starting of their generation , rather only last generated hashname is being passed.

Comment: @shailendra: You misunderstood me. You did not generate hashnames, you just have iterated through all possible combinations, ending at `zzzz`.

Comment: ok..i am still confused with respect to this, so how can i get those different hashname, when i used your code and print `str` it printed only one random name and if possible , how can i use my code to produce hashname, rather then iterating through them...

Comment: because in my another code, when a bit different code, it stored aaaa and after then produced seh fault

Comment: what i was asking is that i have to assign a random hashname to a structures in which some variables are stored.Means there is a code which read a file, parse it, and find some signal names, but they are quite big, so what i want to do is generate random hashname and store them in those structures, so that while writing those signals in a file, i can replace them with their hashname so as to reduce the size of file....and easiest way to create random hashname  i found is this..

Comment: how can i use ur code to generate n different hashname ans assign them to n structures

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38410/discussion-between-shailendra-and-liho)